# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SaturdayTest/welcome] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-dispatcher'

Tags: spring-mvc

No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SaturdayTest/welcome] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-dispatcher'

I can't find where the mistake is done.

HelloController.java

```
package com.prav.hellocontroller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloController  {


@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public ModelAndView helloWorld() {
    ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView("HelloPage");
    model.addObject("msg","hello world");
    return model;
}    }
```

HelloPage.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

</head>
<body>
<h1>${msg}<h1>
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" 
version="3.1">

<display-name>SaturdayTest</display-name>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">



<context:component-scan base-package="com.prav.hellocontroller">
</context:component-scan>

<bean id="viewResolver" 
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

<property name="prefix">
<value>/WEB-INF/</value>
</property>
<property name="suffix">
<value>.jsp</value>
</property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

checked the dispatcher and mapping, but the name is same.Where can be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
@RequestMapping("SaturdayTest")
```

on top of your controller. Like:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("SaturdayTest")
public class HelloController  {
```

Let me know it this works.

Comment: Yes. Remove the `@RequestMapping("SaturdayTest")`, i suggested earlier. Now on your method, provide `@RequestMapping("")` i.e. remove /welcome. Now share the result of accessing root.

Answer (score 0):

@RequestMapping("/SaturdayTest/welcome")
Try with this annotation on your method

Comment: @karthy stack trace?